# Counting and matching process

Tags: awk, match

I have a matching problem with awk :(

I will count first column elements in main.file and if its value is more than 2 I will print the first and the second column.

main.file

```
1725009 7211378
3353866 11601802
3353866 8719104
724973 3353866
3353866 7211378
```

For example number of "3353866" in the first column is 3, so output.file will be like that:

output.file

```
3353866 11601802
3353866 8719104
3353866 7211378
```

How can I do this in awk?

Comment: Do you mean if the first digit of the number in the first column is more than 2?  If so, why does 724973 not count?

Comment: No, I do not mean digits. I mean numbers.another example should be like that:

Comment: can you reformat the question, then?  All of the first column numbers are larger than 2.  I might have edited it wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ray, agree, the question doesn't make sense. -1

Answer (score 1):

If you mean items with at least 3 occurrences, you can collect occurrences in one array and the collected values as a preformatted or delimited string in another.

```
awk '{o[$1]++;v[$1]=v[$1] "\n" $0}
    END{for(k in o){if(o[k]<3)continue;
        print(substr(v[k],1)}' main.file
```

Untested, not at my computer. The output order will be essentially random; you'll need another variable to keep track of line numbers if you require the order to be stable.

This would be somewhat less hackish in Perl or Python, where a hash/dict can contain a structured value, such as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to run through the file twice: it's a little bit slower, but the code is very neat:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {count[$1]++; next}
  count[$1] > 2 {print}
' main.file main.file
```

Comment: You can do this in a single pass

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{store[$1"-"lines[$1]] = $0; lines[$1]++;}
  END {for (l in store) {
    split(l, pair, "-"); if (lines[pair[1]] > 2) { print store[l] } } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to track all the records seen, the corresponding key `$1` for each record, and how often each key occurs. Once you've record those for all the lines, you can then iterate through all the records stored, only printing those for which the count of the key is greater than two.

```
awk '{ 
    record[NR] = $0; 
    key[$0] = $1; 
    count[$1]++ 
} 

END { 
    for (n=1; n <= length(record); n++) { 
        if (count[key[record[n]]] > 2) { 
            print record[n] 
        }
    } 
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort first, and then use awk to print only when you have 3 times or more the 1st field:

```
cat your_file | sort -n | awk 'prev == $1 {count++; p0=p1; p1=p2; p2=$2}
prev != $1 {prev=$1; count=1; p2=$2}
count == 3 {print $1 " " p0; print $1 " " p1; print $1 " " p2}
count > 3 {print $1 " " $2}'
```

This will avoid awk to use too much memory in case of big input file.

Comment: you have just been awarded the [UUoC-award}(http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) :-) No need for cat, sort can take a file as input directly...

Comment: @Fredrick: I know that sort can take a file as input  directly, but I think it is clearer that way, especially showing that the input can come from somewhere else than a file.  The same applies to `awk 'a very large script' file` that I write `cat file | awk 'a very large script'` with I think is clearer to understand and to figure out where the input of awk is comming.

Comment: don't agree... but you offer an explanation showing that you put some thought behind it.

Answer (score 0):

based on how the question looks and the Ray Toal edit, I'm guessing you mean based on count, so something like this works:

```
awk '!y[$1] {y[$1] = 1} x[$1] {if(y[$1]==1) {y[$1]==2; print $1, x[$1]}; print} {x[$1] = $2}'
```